# restaurar base de datos visual studio 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server-management

Necesito cargar un archivo *.BAK* en la base de datos  `SQL server` en `Visual studio 2019`. No puedo encontrar en el menú alguna opcion de restaurar o cargar el archivo y cuando intento la consulta sql para restaurar la bd, me solicita una variable.

A continuacion dejo la consulta Sql:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Rapifacil
FROM 'C\Rapifacil\Rapifacil.bak
WITH REPLACE
```

de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Check this: https://www.stellarinfo.com/article/restore-sql-server-database-from-bak-file.php

Comment: Esta pregunta es de base de datos, ¿por qué la etiquetas como c# o visual studio? En el SQL Server Manangement Studio al darle click derecho en Bases de Datos, te aparecerá la opción para restaurar.